# Is there a way to save the Visual Studio workspace manually?

Tags: visual-studio

I've given up trying to stop VS from crashing (usually 2 to 3 times a day). Now I'm moving on to finding a way limit the amount of work that needs to be redone when I re-open my project after a crash.

When VS crashes, any changes you have made to the workspace such as which files are open, pinned etc are gone. Any breakpoints, bookmarks etc are also gone. If VS is shutdown normally without crashing then all these workspace changes are saved, but if it crashes they're lost. I am now at the point where I deliberately shutdown VS every so often just so that any changes will be saved when it inevitably crashes.

Is there a way to manually save the workspace?

Comment: what version of VS?  I never get VS crashing.

Comment: @KeithNicholas - 2013 pro. It crashes sometimes when running the debugger.

Comment: oh....  any reason why not use 2017?

Comment: @KeithNicholas - mostly it is a question of finding time to make changes to our library to make it compatible with versions post 2013.

Comment: you sure there's anything you have to do? most things are automatic.  Though nuget dependencies might need to be redone cleanly

Comment: @KeithNicholas - yes there are conflicts in some defines which a lot of our library relies on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may come across this, the problem seems to have been related to a plugin called VisualAssist. A recent update seems to have completely fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

**File - Save all** should save most of the current workspace configuration.

Comment: What makes you say that? I habitually press Ctrl-Shift-S but still have this problem all the time.